# Excel: Count cells that contain weekday

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column with dates in column U. I changed them to "ddd" format, so now they are Mon, Tue etc.
[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to count how many times `Mon` is in cells between cell `U2` and `U1048576`.
I tried `=COUNTIF(U2:U1048576,Mon)` and `=COUNTIF(U2:U1048576,"Mon")`. Result is always 0. I tried same thing but searching for a number and it works. How do I do same thing for weekdays ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the format does not change the value.  Your dates are still numbers to Excel, just formatted to show a string.  As such Excel does not find a string.

COUNTIFS() will not work without a helper column.  You need to use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(U2:INDEX(U:U,MATCH(1E+99,U:U)))=2))
```

SUMPRODUCT is an array type formula.  Therefore one should not use full column references.

The `U2:INDEX(U:U,MATCH(1E+99,U:U))` sets the reference range to only those with numbers.  This way it is not doing unnecessary calculations.

WEEKDAY() returns the day number 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ...

The SUMPRODUCT() will count when the criteria = TRUE.  The `--` Changes TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.

Comment: Thank you! So as I understand at the very end of formula =2 means count Mon, =3 Tue?

Comment: @Powisss yes that is correct.

Comment: Additionally, if you wanted to have one formula to count all the weekdays, you could change it to `=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(U2:INDEX(U:U,MATCH(1E+99,U:U)),2)<6))`. Adding a `2` as the `return_value` in the `Weekday` function shifts the starting point so 1=Monday and 7=Sunday. Anything <6, therefore, is Mon-Fri.